# Accessing Properties from Another Project in Quarkus-Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, quarkus

I'm developing one common library in one of project. I'm currently using gradle and kotlin
I've one projects say **notifications** it needs to get one dependencies of another project say **common-lib**

so in **notifications** project, in application.yaml file if I mention property of any database in this format.

```
datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/some-test-db
        driver: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: USERNAME
        password: PASSWORD
```

How will I read this properties in **common-lib**, also how will I add **common-lib** dependency in **notifications** project if I'm working in local. Please help.

```
datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/some-test-db
        driver: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: USERNAME
        password: PASSWORD
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this I'd imagine and I'm no Quarkus expert but is there an option to have the "values" in the yml config refer to env vars instead?  That is what we do in my current project (not Quarkus).

Comment: Apologies if I misread your question but you could also default the value to something when the env var is not available as well.